# Django in python

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to make a site with Django Framework but I receive this error:
`excepted 'endblock', did you forget to register or load this tag?`

This is the code:

```html
<form action="{% url 'learning_logs:new_entry' topic. Id %}" method="post">
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: please provide that template

Comment: Most probably you forget some `endblock` kindly check it.

Comment: please add full code of template

Answer (score 0):

## --- add code between block like this ---

```
{% block body %}
     <form action="{% url 'learning_logs:new_entry' topic. Id %}" method="post">
  
     </form>
{% endblock body %}
```